# View message body of push notification sent via Firebase API in Firebase console

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I am using the Flutter framework to send a device push notification to the Andriod device using FCM API. I can see that message is delivered to the device, however, I want to see the details of the message being sent over the period, e.g. last month. Currently, in the console, it shows only statistics, not the details. Is there any way I can see details like to whom message being send [device token], what was the message title, body etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not available using FCM API. Created our own repo, and achieved the goal!!